# Error: No user assignments exist error in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

From Azure portal, I'm trying to do "Assign the Service Desk Virtual Machine Contributor permissions"

I have created user:
[image: User details]

Created a VM:
[image: VM]

Searching by Name:
[image: No user]

However, the search says no user assignment exists.

What am I doing wrong/missing? Any suggestion please? Thanks

Comment: I can se that you have assigned a Group to the role but is searching for the user which is part of that group (my guess), so it should not show. What you should search is the "Service Desk" group you have added in the RG level. Because "Dylan" is part of the Group and that Group has role in the RG. (get it?)

Comment: Hello @AskMe, Rockstar is correct .. I would please like to know that is the new user that you have created a part of the Service Desk group? 
Are You searching the user to assign the role separately as its not part of service desk group?

Comment: Hello @AskMe, Any update on this ?

Comment: Hello @AskMe, If the below answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Rockstar** has mentioned in comments section, If the `user` is a part **Service Desk Group** then in IAM blade the user won't be visible but if you check the ***user's azure role assignment*** then you will find the role which was assigned to the group has been inherited by the user as well.

If the user is not a part of the group then you have to directly assign the Role in IAM blade for the user itself to make it visible in the Portal IAM Blade.

**I tested in my environment like this:**

1.Created a user and added him to the service desk group

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wUlt2D5.png]

2.Assigned virtual machine contributor role to the group

[image: https://i.imgur.com/f5rXLQX.png]

3.And then I go to the User>>azure role assignment and I see that role is assigned to the user as well as it is a part of the group

[image: https://i.imgur.com/aEVcLQI.png]

4.And assigned  another user(not part of service desk group) to the role and I can see it in the portal

[image: https://i.imgur.com/hxMmqi9.png]